# Pegar JavaScript/jQuery em um botão

Tags: jquery

Tenho esse botão:

```
<div class="grid_17">
    <button value="novaPesquisa" class="btn-pular-passo pull-right" id="btnEndereco">Continuar</button>
</div>
```

Existe um `<form>` bem grande, onde esse botão está inserido, tudo dividido por DIV's. Bem, acontece que algumas DIV's, elas entram com `Display="none"` e elas somente serã visiveis, no click desse botão. Eu fiz uma validação de campos em branco e logo, quando há campos em branco, já mostra um "hint" no próprio componente dizendo que aquele campo precisa ser preenchido. Bem, tenho os seguintes problemas. A função de validação, ela pega todo o form e todas as DIV's, inclusive a do botão e as que estão `hide`, estão dentro desse form. Ai pergunto? Será que funciona ou terei que criar dois forms: um para os campos que já entram aparecendo e o botão e outro form para os que estão escondidos ou não? E como eu faço isso no botão, ou seja, saber se foram ou não validados? Abaixo a função jQuery para validar.

```
var validateOptions = {
    ignore: "",
    errorElement: false,
    highlight: function (field) {
        $(field).addClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
    },
    unhighlight: function (field) {
        $(field).addClass('has-success').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorPlacement: function () {
    }
};

$('#formConfirmaDados').data('validate', $('#formConfirmaDados').validate(validateOptions));
```

Answer (score 1):

Para validar somente os visiveis você pode utilizar o `ignore` do `validateOptions`

```
var validateOptions = {
   ignore: ":not(:visible)", //Aqui está o que precisa fazer para validar somente os campos visíveis
   errorElement: false,
   highlight: function (field) {
      $(field).addClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
   },
   unhighlight: function (field) {
      $(field).addClass('has-success').removeClass('has-error');
   },
   errorPlacement: function () {
   }
};

$('#formConfirmaDados').data('validate', $('#formConfirmaDados').validate(validateOptions));
```

Comment: Normal... Você vai ver, quanto mais você usar e aprender, mais difícil vai ficar para entender o jquery... brincadeira

Comment: Como eu faço agora para mostrar os demais depois de todos os campos serem preenchidos? Ao apertar o botão, se estiver em branco, ele "grita" que o campo precisa ser preenchido. E quando estiver preenchidos, como eu faço para mostrar as DIV's que estão com display="none"?

Comment: Em relação a exibir os display="none" é simples, basta fazer algo como `$('.div:not(:visible)').show()` agora eu não entendi muito o que seria gritar... seria chamar a atenção para o campo não preenchido?

Comment: Gritar, foi gíria minha, ou seja, se o campo está vazio ele exibe logo uma mensagem que precisa ser preenchido(gritar), desculpe-me, é o hábito de inventar jargão, pregão e etc... Isso eu faço em uma nova function ou na mesma? Em momento, caso seja na mesma

Comment: remove a linha `errorPlacement: function() { }` q ele deve exibir já do lado do campo

Comment: Fiz assim, mas não funcionou.  $('#btnEndereco').click(function () {
                $('#endereco').css('display:""');
            });

Comment: Quando um campo está visível em jquery vc utiliza o `$('element').hide()` para esconder e para mostrar o elemento vc utiliza o `$('element').show()`... então no seu exemplo para exibir o campo endereço, você deveria fazer algo assim:  `$('#btnEndereco').click(function () { $('#endereco').show(); });`

Comment: vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13663/discussion-between-tchicotti-and-pnet)

Comment: Como eu posto uma pergunta no chat?